# Alternative to AirPcap for Linux?

Tags: network, linux, wifi, sniffer

I need to sniff WiFi packets, but according to [AirPcap FAQ page](http://www.airpcap.nl/faq-airpcap.htm), it just supports Microsoft Windows, not other platforms. Does any alternative of this product work in Linux?

Please don't offer `Alfa` WiFi Adapter, because it cannot receive some packets!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Airpcap-Nx](http://www.airpcap.nl/airpcap-nx.htm). It uses *[Atheros AR9001U-2NX](http://wikidevi.com/wiki/CACE_Technologies_AirPcap_Nx)* chip-set which is installed and patched on `Backtrack` and `Kali` by default.

Answer (score 4):

You can use to normal wireless cards and change the mode to Monitor mode .

Ralink and Atheros cheapests are best choices .

Aircrack-ng's website have [compatibility drivers page](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compatibility_drivers), since that proposed good device for WiFi sniffing data and raw packet injection, you can use that :

[Best wireless USB proposed devices](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compatibility_drivers#usb)

Answer (score 0):

Some normal wifi card doesn't allow to change to monitor mode. To overcome this, you can use external wifi adapters such TPLink WIFI Adapater since it works well with Linux as it is Ralink based chipset.

Comment: Are you sure ?
 Monitor Mode is a defined and standard mode in linux systmes !

http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/modes#Monitor_.28MON.29_mode

Comment: Monitor mode is arguably layer1 through layer3.  So the NIC itself and the driver both need to cooperate with monitor mode before Linux can leverage it.  I don't think this answer is really helpful to the OP as it sounds like the real intent in a full range packet injection solution.  This answer is not "wrong" tho.